# $\text{Cocone}(D,Y)\simeq \mathscr C(X,Y)\implies X=\text{colim} D$

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

I'm transferring here the discussion from the comments in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3741497/on-the-proof-of-the-density-theorem).

The problem is as follows: Suppose $D:I\to \mathscr C$ is a diagram (= functor) and suppose there's a bijection $$\text{Cocone}(D,Y)\simeq \mathscr C(X,Y)$$
between the cocones on $D$ with vertex $Y$ and arrows $X\to Y$, and this bijection is natural in $Y$. How to prove that $X=\text{colim} D$? The definition of colimit can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.09375.pdf) (p. 126).

I understand how to prove the reverse implication, but the implication described above is unclear.

Consider a cocone $(f_i:D(i)\to Y)_{i\in I}$. We know that there is a unique arrow $\bar f:X\to Y$. That's all I can do. For example, it's not clear what the coprojections $D(i)\to X$ are.

Comment: Are you sure you do not require your bijections to be natural?  That is for every object $Y$ you have such a bijection and for any morphism $f:Y_1 \to Y_2$ you have a commutative square consisting of the bijections for $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ and the induced maps on Cocones and morphisms.

Comment: If so, then you get your coprojections by taking the preimage of $1_X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll follow tkf's hint.

Suppose we have a bijection $$\text{Cocone}(D,Y)\simeq \mathscr C(X,Y)$$ that is natural in $Y$.

Let's write $$\text{Cocone}(D,Y)\to\mathscr C(X,Y)$$ as $$(f_i)_{i\in I}\mapsto \bar f$$ and its inverse $$\mathscr C(X,Y)\to \text{Cocone}(D,Y)$$ as $$g\mapsto (\widehat g_i)_{i\in I}$$

We show that $((\widehat {1_X})_i: D(i)\to X)_{i\in I}$ is a limit cocone on $D$ in $\mathscr C$. Suppose $(f_i:D(i)\to Y)_{i\in I}$ is a cocone on $D$ in $\mathscr C$. We know that there exists a unique $\bar f:X\to Y$. To prove that $((\widehat {1_X})_i: D(i)\to X)_{i\in I}$ is a limit cocone, it remains to prove that $\bar f\circ (\widehat{1_X})_i=f_i$ for all $i\in I$.

To this end, we use the naturality of the given bijection in $Y$ with respect to $\bar f:X\to Y$. This naturality amounts to saying that the following diagram commutes:

[image]

Since bar and hat are inverses of each other, the equality at the bottom says $$(\bar f \circ (\widehat{1_X})_i)_{i\in I}=(f_i)_{i\in I}$$
implying that $\bar f\circ (\widehat{1_X})_i=f_i$ for all $i\in I$.