# Expressing a presheaf as a colimit of representables

Tags: category-theory, proof-explanation, representable-functor

I don't understand how the highlighted isomorphism follows. And why is every object in $\mathbf {Set}\times\mathbf{Set}$ is a sum of copies of $(1,\emptyset)$ and $(\emptyset,1)$?

[image]

Next, right after [the density theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3741497/on-the-proof-of-the-density-theorem), there's this example:

[image]

By the theorem, the colimit of $H_\bullet \circ P$ is $X$. This example says that the colimit is the sum of five representables, namely $H_K+H_K+H_K+H_L+H_L$. How does this follow from the theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think $1$ is a one-point set, and "sum" here is coproduct. In the category of sets,
coproduct is disjoint union. Likewise in $\textbf{Set}\times\textbf{Set}$
the coproduct of $(A_1,B_1)$ and $(A_2,B_2)$ is $(A_1+ A_2,B_1+ B_2)$.
This extends to coproducts of more than two objects, even infinitely many objects.

So
$$(\{a,b,c\},\{d,e\})\cong(\{a\},\emptyset)+(\{b\},\emptyset)+(\{c\},\emptyset)
+(\emptyset,\{d\})+(\emptyset,\{e\})
\cong(1,\emptyset)+(1,\emptyset)+(1,\emptyset)
+(\emptyset,1)+(\emptyset,1)$$
etc.