# Coproducts in $\textbf{Set}\times \textbf{Set}$

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

The answer in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3744636/expressing-a-presheaf-as-a-colimit-of-representables) says that the coproduct  $(A_1,B_1)+(A_2,B_2)$ in $\textbf{Set}\times \textbf{Set}$ is $(A_1+A_2,B_1+B_2)$. Why is this the case? I suppose this is a special case of some general result, but I don't understand which one. The closest result about "pointwise computation" that I can think of is that limits/colimits in functor categories are computed pointwise, but there's no functor categories here.

Comment: Hint: $\textbf{Set} \times \textbf{Set}$ is equivalent to a functor category. Which one?

Answer (score 4):

You can also argue with product categories directly (no functor categories are required), and in a much more general situation as well. If $(\mathcal{C}_i)_{i \in I}$ is a family of categories with coproducts, then coproducts in $\prod_{i \in I} \mathcal{C}_i$ are computed "pointwise", i.e., for a family $(A_j)_{j \in J}$ in $\prod_{i \in I} \mathcal{C}_i$ we have
$$\coprod_{j \in J} A_j = \Bigl(\coprod_{j \in J} A_{ji}\Bigr)_{i \in I},$$
where we abbreviate $A_{ji} := (A_j)_i$. The proof just uses the definitions. Only in $\stackrel{!}{=}$ something is happening, namely that products of sets commute with products of sets.
$$\hom\Bigl(\Bigl(\coprod_{j \in J} A_{j,i}\Bigr)_{i \in I},B\Bigr) = \prod_{i \in I} \hom\Bigl(\coprod_{j \in J} A_{ji},B_i\Bigr) = \prod_{i \in I} \prod_{j \in J} \hom(A_{ji},B_i)$$
$$ \stackrel{!}{=} \prod_{j \in J} \prod_{i \in I} \hom(A_{ji},B_i) = \prod_{j \in J} \hom(A_j,B)$$

Answer (score 3):

In fact there is. We have an isomorphism of categories $\mathsf{Set} \cong \operatorname{Fun}(*,\mathsf{Set})$. Using this we can deduce
$$\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Fun}(*+*,\mathsf{Set}) &\cong \operatorname{Fun}(*,\mathsf{Set})\times\operatorname{Fun}(*,\mathsf{Set})\\
&\cong \mathsf{Set}\times\mathsf{Set}
\end{align*}$$
So (co)limits in $\mathsf{Set}\times\mathsf{Set}$ are indeed computed pointwise.

Comment: Then I'm still not sure how to "convert" the fact $(X + Y)(A)=X(A)+Y(A)$ into $(A_1,B_1)+(A_2,B_2)=(A_1+A_2, B_1+B_2)$...

Comment: @user634426 If the index category is named $\{1,2\}$, then $(X+Y)(1) = X(1) + Y(1)$ and $(X+Y)(2) = X(2) + Y(2)$ shows precisely that $X+Y = (X(1)+Y(1), X(2)+Y(2))$. In other words, $(A_1,A_2) + (B_1,B_2) = (A_1 + B_1 , A_2 + B_2)$. (Your indices are a bit confusing here.)

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg It looks like you're using "$X+Y=((X+Y)(1), (X+Y)(2))$". If this is the case, then why is this equality true?